# Install ROS2 on OS X - Error: No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'

Tags: macos, module, conda, poco, ros2

I am trying to install ros2 env in Mac. I created a conda env for it.

I have installed `conda install -c anaconda sphinx` and `conda install -c conda-forge sphinx-autodoc-typehints`.

I got the errors when I ran `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker`:

```
Failed to load entry point 'test': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'launch': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'info': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
.
.
.
Failed to load entry point 'list': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
Failed to load entry point 'pub': No module named 'rclpy._rclpy'
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/poco/lib/libPocoFoundation.63.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/linfeng/workspace/ros2_dashing/ros2-osx/lib/librosidl_typesupport_c.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Any idea? Thank you in advance

Comment: I installed `conda install -c conda-forge rosdep rospkg`, then re-tar the ros2 resource file. It still did not work. Is there a conda package for **ROS2**?

Answer (score 3):

I got it working by linking the newer installed `poco` version:

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/poco/lib/libPocoFoundation.71.dylib /usr/local/opt/poco/lib/libPocoFoundation.63.dylib
```